# Sharing JavaFX css values across multiple classes

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-css

How can I share settings across multiple classes? I need to apply certain styles to my tableview cells (depending on the enum value displayed) and would prefer not to repeat the values as below -

```
.A { 
    -fx-background-color: red;
}

.B { 
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Just add the class name to the stylesheet of the cell.

Comment: I have created one style class for each java enum present in my model. Some of these classes have the same settings. Hence my aim to reduce css duplication. 

This way I can set the string value of an enum as the style class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply rules to multiple selectors with

```
.A, .B {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [Skinning JavaFX Applications with CSS](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm) tutorial and the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

*Excerpt:*

You can create a class style by adding a definition for it to your style sheet. Example 5 defines a new style in controlStyle1.css called .button1.

Example 5 Define a New Style

```
.button1{
    -fx-text-fill: #006464;
    -fx-background-color: #DFB951;
    -fx-border-radius: 20;
    -fx-background-radius: 20;
    -fx-padding: 5;
}
```

To assign this class style to a node, use the getStyleClass().add() sequence of methods. Example 6 shows the .button1 style assigned to the Accept button.

```
Button buttonAccept = new Button("Accept");
buttonAccept.getStyleClass().add("button1");
```